# Npgsql Syntax Error at or near ":"

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, npgsql

I've been looking at this for a few days now and I've done a lot of testing but I still can't get it to work. I'm using Npgsql 2.0.11.91 (I tried 2.0.11 as well) and PostgreSQL 9.04.

Using the example from the User Manual for Npgsql which can be found [here](http://npgsql.projects.postgresql.org/docs/manual/UserManual.html). Search for "Working with .NET Datasets" to see the example. It works fine for me as it is but I'm trying to modify it to suit my needs.

My code is below. No matter what I try I get some sort of error. Using the code below which is pretty much exactly what's in the user manual I get an NpgsqlException was unhandled by user code

```
ERROR: 42601: syntax error at or near ":".
```

```cs
private void tryThis()
{
    // This method expects the following table in the backend:
    //
    //  create table customers(code varchar, reference varchar, description varchar, street varchar, suburb varchar, postcode varchar);
    //
    //

    NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;User Id=postgres;Password=password;Database=testdatabase;");
    conn.Open();

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter("select * from customers", conn);

    da.InsertCommand = new NpgsqlCommand("insert into customers(code, reference, description, street, suburb, postcode) " +
                                " values (:a, :b, :c, :d, :e, :f)", conn);

    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("a", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar));
    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("b", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar));
    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("c", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar));
    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("e", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar));
    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("e", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar));
    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("f", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar));

    da.InsertCommand.Parameters[0].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    da.InsertCommand.Parameters[1].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    da.InsertCommand.Parameters[2].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    da.InsertCommand.Parameters[3].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    da.InsertCommand.Parameters[4].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    da.InsertCommand.Parameters[5].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

    da.InsertCommand.Parameters[0].SourceColumn = "code";
    da.InsertCommand.Parameters[1].SourceColumn = "reference";
    da.InsertCommand.Parameters[2].SourceColumn = "description";
    da.InsertCommand.Parameters[3].SourceColumn = "street";
    da.InsertCommand.Parameters[4].SourceColumn = "suburb";
    da.InsertCommand.Parameters[5].SourceColumn = "postcode";

    da.Fill(ds);

    DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];

    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["code"] = "CUST1";
    dr["reference"] = "C";
    dr["description"] = "Customer 1";
    dr["street"] = "1 Big Street";
    dr["suburb"] = "BRISBANE QLD";
    dr["postcode"] = "4000";
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

    DataSet ds2 = ds.GetChanges();

    da.Update(ds2);

    ds.Merge(ds2);
    ds.AcceptChanges();
}
```

Any ideas?

Pete.

Comment: Using the straight ADO.NET classes, normally you specify the whole parameter name (i.e., if you put `@id` in the query, the parameter name has to be `"@id"`, not `"id"`). Try adding the colons to the parameter names?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You add the param `e` twice while not adding the param `d` at all...

EDIT (from your code above):

```cs
da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("e", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar));
da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("e", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar));
```

Comment: Wow that's embarrassing. Thanks! Time for a break I think.

Comment: There are 3 ways you can try to go in order to find this problem. 1. NpgsqlException has an ErrorSql property which tells you which sql gave the problem. 2. You can enable Npgsql logging and check which sql Npgsql is sending to the server. 3. You can enable postgresql server logging and check which queries are being received. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I was also having problems, following the npgsql documentation, and getting errors when declaring parameters with the colon.
It turns out in the latest version you can use the .NET style AddWithValue, eg,

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paramName", paramValue);
```